# How to use multiple custom listviews in a single activity?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to create multiple custom listview in android.I will show one list with checkbox and depending on user choice I want to show the second list with checkboxs in the same view.Is it possible? I searched for multiple listviews but didnt get something which I want.Kindly help.

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is the master-detail pane

Comment: You can use `Fragments`..

Comment: I am using fragment to display one list inside the same fragment I want to display another list depending on user choice.I want something like expandable list view but the next list should expand only if the user selects a particular checkbox

Comment: Try `ExpandableListView`. Here is a nice tutorial: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129